# Get current .htaccess directory from PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

So, I'm trying to create a custom directory index which displays images. I managed to get it working, but I ran into one problem. I set the `.htaccess` to execute a script, which executes the actual script in another directory. When the script runs it gives the directory listing of the directory the redirection script is in, rather than the directory the `.htaccess` is in. How can I get around this?

Here is my `.htaccess`:

```
Options Indexes
IndexIgnore *.log .htaccess *.htaccess
DirectoryIndex /spic/imgform/picview.php
```

The file `/spic/imgform/picview.php` contains this:

```
<?php include '/var/www/html/src/script/viewimg.php' ?>
```

Apparently it shows the `/spic/imgform` directory, rather than the intended directory where the `.htaccess` is located.

Comment: It could be help us a bit, if you show us your `.htaccess` file, and tell something about your directory structure.

Comment: @vaso123 Ok, I'll make the edits.

Comment: Fast fix would be, when redirecting to the php file, add a request var in the .htaccess with the folderpath needed  and then use `chdir()` in php to switch to the right directory.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Ok, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script still has access to the global [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variables, especially `DOCUMENT_ROOT` and `REQUEST_URI`, which can be combined to the relevant path. So in your script, you could

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
// change to $path or display it directly
```

Comment: `DOCUMENT_ROOT` + `REQUEST_URI` isn't always the directory of the .htaccess, but the requested directory, which may be the directory of .htaccess.

Comment: Should use . instead of + for concatenation